# Why is the following example not jointly stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I am reading the textbook by Fumio Hayashi. He uses the following example to illustrate the difference between elementwise and joint stationarity. However, I do not understand why the vector process is not joint statiionary.

[image]

Comment: Could you please fix the notation up?  Use mathjax if you can, that will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is already written, the answer is that the joint distribution of $z_1$ is different from that of $z_2$, and that is because $z_1= (e_1,e_1)$ has a CDF like:

$$P(e_1 \le a, e_1 \le b) = P(e_1 \le \min(a,b))$$ because of course $e_1 = e_1$, hence they are fully dependent.

The CDF of $z_1= (e_1,e_2)$ instead is the product of the CDFs of $e_1$ and $e_2$ since they are independent.

Hence the two PDFs are different.